# Building static library in aosp

Tags: android-source, android-soong

I am trying to built a static library in aosp, which is then used by another program.

Android.bp is for the static library is as follows:

```
cc_library_static {
    name: "libabc",

    srcs: [
        "src/abc.c",
        "src/abcd.c",
    ],

    include_dirs: [
        "my_folder/inc",
    ],
    vendor: true,
}
```

Although the build is successful, I am not able to find my *libabc.a* in my outputs folder.

Do I have to add *libabc.a* in PRODUCT_PACKAGES for it to be added to the build ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Why would you want to have static libraries on your device? Soong will build `libabc` as soon as a package in `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` depends on it.

Comment: @Simpl so how does it link my static lib to my sample program ? While building my sample program, I am getting link error. So I thought I had to include libabc.a path to srcs

Comment: I did add the libabc in static_libs section of Android.bp for sample program

Comment: Adding `libabc` to your modules `static_libs` is correct. Please attach your linker error.

Comment: @Simpl It throws "error : undefined reference to functions_in_libabc"

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without the seeing sources. My first guess is that your build configuration is fine and the `functions_in_libabc` is not in any files listed in your `srcs` list.

You can find `libabc.a` in `out/soong/.intermediates/` and check whether it contains your missing reference.

```sh
nm $(find $ANDROID_BUILD_TOP/out/soong/.intermediates -name 'libabc.a')
```

All you have to do in the module depending on `libabc` is adding it to the `static_libs` list.

```
cc_binary {
    name: "my-module",
    srcs: [ "main.cpp" ],
    static_libs: [ "libabc" ],
}
```